# Model an infrequent linear feature in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, feature-extraction

I am trying to predict energy usage of homes. I have a feature (home square footage) that is highly useful when available, but is often not available (in which case it is 0).

I want TensorFlow to ignore the feature if it is 0, but otherwise incorporate it in a linear model (which supports a neural net).

Is there a type of feature column that can do something like this?

Currently I am doing:

```
square_footage_buckets = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(
    square_footage, boundaries=[.01, 1000, 2500, 5000, 20000])
```

But this makes really bad predictions for skyscrapers - it treats them the same as your local home depot (and I don't have training data for skyscrapers, so I don't want to add another bucket)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by: *but otherwise incorporate it in a linear model* ? Do you explicitly want a linear model?

Comment: I'm using a deep/wide combined model. It doesn't necessarily have to be linear, but that's what I thought made sense.

Comment: I expect energy usage to scale linearly with square footage, but only if square footage data is available (greater than 0)